# failed to get config: cannot resolve the configuration:cannot retrieve the configuration:unable to read the file file:/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml

Tags: otel

opensource-otel-collector-1  | Error: failed to get config: cannot resolve the configuration: cannot retrieve the configuration: unable to read the file file:/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml: read /etc/otel-collector-config.yaml: is a directory
opensource-otel-collector-1  | 2023/04/10 21:30:28 collector server run finished with error: failed to get config: cannot resolve the configuration: cannot retrieve the configuration: unable to read the file file:/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml: read /etc/otel-collector-config.yaml: is a directory

I followed the steps here for the docker-compose option to start a otel collector - https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/getting-started/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

That just because docker couldn't find this file on host system ->
**otel-collector-config.yaml**. Check for the file name if you already have that file or mounting path.